# (Beamer) No frametitle and no redundant vertical spacing

Tags: beamer

In Berkeley theme, I have some slides that have frametitle and some slides that doesn't have frametitle. For slides without frametitle, I want the vertical space for the title area would be zero. How can I do this?

I provide a simple example code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This has frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
contents without frametitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\begin{frame}[plain]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the headline for these frames and then force a recalculation of the page geometry:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calculateheadfoot}{\beamer@calculateheadfoot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This has frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\calculateheadfoot
\begin{frame}
contents without frametitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This has frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Update:

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e5c868041cb51c278420d0b4189693ed569ee3d9) (should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), beamer now recalculates the head- and footheight at the start of each frame, so the workaround is no longer necessary:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Berkeley}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This has frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
contents without frametitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This has frametitle}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```